# Community Screen Flow Date Input Error Message wrong?

Tags: visual-workflow, lightninginput, screen-flow

A client I am working with has a 'registration' screen flow that captures customer information and is on a Salesforce Community behind a login wall. For some reason the Date Input shows a funky error message (that isn't accurate) when validating the input.

When the user enters a birthrate in an incorrect format, the following error message is shown.  'Your entry does not match the allowed format MMM d, yyyy.'
We would like it to show 'dd/mm/yyyy' as thats the required format for the input (its a date input).

I am thinking this is related to this outstanding Locale issue?  Most of the googling I have done indicates this is a issue more commonly found when making custom lightning components, but we are using a screen flow and don't have control over the native SF inputs.

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000FmAgQAK&title=lightning-input-date-locale-format